# Not able to display data from API using retrofit on a recyclerview

Tags: java, android

**MAIN ACTIVITY**

> When i try to debug the app its not entering in to the **on Respone** method, its crashing before that .

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
RecyclerView recyclerView;
ArrayList<EarthQuakeObject> earthquakes;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
earthquakes =getEarthquakeData();
EarthQuakeAdapter adapter = new EarthQuakeAdapter(MainActivity.this, 
earthquakes);
LinearLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new 
LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

}

public ArrayList<EarthQuakeObject> getEarthquakeData() {

EarthquakeApi earthquakeApi = 
RetrofitClient.getRetrofitInstance().create(EarthquakeApi.class);
Call<JSONObject> call = earthquakeApi.getEarthquakeInfo();

Log.e("MainActivity", String.valueOf(call.request().body()));


call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<JSONObject> call, Response<JSONObject> response) {


if(response.isSuccessful()) {
JSONObject responseObject = response.body();

try {
JSONArray array = responseObject.getJSONArray("features");
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject completeData = array.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONObject properties = completeData.getJSONObject("properties");
    double magnitude = properties.getDouble("mag");
    double time = properties.getDouble("time");
    String place = properties.getString("place");
EarthQuakeObject earthQuakeObject = new EarthQuakeObject(magnitude,place,time);
    earthquakes.add(earthQuakeObject);
}



} catch (JSONException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
  }
}


        }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<JSONObject> call, Throwable t) {
        System.out.println(t.getMessage());

    }


});

return earthquakes;
}



}
```

**ADAPTER CLASS**

> Its showing a null pointer exception - **java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method int java.util.ArrayList.size() on a null object reference**

```
'public class EarthQuakeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EarthQuakeAdapter.EarthQuakeViewHolder>{
private Context mctx;
private ArrayList<EarthQuakeObject> earthQuakeObjectList;

public EarthQuakeAdapter(Context mctx, ArrayList<EarthQuakeObject> earthQuakeObjectList) {
    this.mctx = mctx;
    this.earthQuakeObjectList = earthQuakeObjectList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public EarthQuakeViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(mctx).inflate(R.layout.grid_layout,parent,false);
    return new EarthQuakeViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull EarthQuakeViewHolder holder, int position) {
    EarthQuakeObject earthQuakeObject = earthQuakeObjectList.get(position);
    holder.mag.setText(""+earthQuakeObject.getmMagnitude());
    holder.place.setText(earthQuakeObject.getmPlace());
    holder.date.setText(""+earthQuakeObject.getmDate());


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return earthQuakeObjectList.size();
}

public class EarthQuakeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView mag;
    TextView place;
  TextView date;
    public EarthQuakeViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mag =itemView.findViewById(R.id.mag);
        place = itemView.findViewById(R.id.place);
        date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
    }



}

}
```

**MODEL CLASS**

```
public class EarthQuakeObject implements Serializable {
@SerializedName("mag")
private double mMagnitude;
@SerializedName("place")
private  String mPlace;
@SerializedName("time")
private  double mDate;

public EarthQuakeObject(double mMagnitude, String mPlace, double mDate) {
    this.mMagnitude = mMagnitude;
    this.mPlace = mPlace;
    this.mDate = mDate;
}

public double getmMagnitude() {
    return mMagnitude;
}

public void setmMagnitude(double mMagnitude) {
    this.mMagnitude = mMagnitude;
}

public String getmPlace() {
    return mPlace;
}

public void setmPlace(String mPlace) {
    this.mPlace = mPlace;
}

public double  getmDate() {
    return mDate;
}

public void setmDate(double mDate) {
    this.mDate = mDate;

}
}'
```

---

### Heading

**RETROFIT CLASS**

```
public class RetrofitClient {
private static Retrofit retrofit;
private static final String base_url ="https://earthquake.usgs.gov";

public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance(){

if(retrofit== null){

retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(base_url)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build();
}

    return  retrofit;
    }
}
```

**INTERFACE**

```
public interface EarthquakeApi {


@GET("/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&starttime=2016-01-01&endtime=2016-01-31&minmag=6&limit=10")
Call<JSONObject> getEarthquakeInfo();
}
```

**ERROR LOG**

```
2019-09-26 19:38:10.724 6634-6634/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.quakereport, PID: 6634
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.quakereport.EarthQuakeAdapter.getItemCount(EarthQuakeAdapter.java:46)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:3834)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3639)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4194)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:446)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:726)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2346)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2068)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6337)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:621)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: your error explaind everything. the time you created the object of adapter you send the null instead of an arraylist and in the method getItemCound when it try to find the length of null list it's get crashed to avoid this check the nullability in your getItemCount method

Comment: Thanks it solved the nullpointer exception, but still the data is not displayed on the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Init. your ArrayList in MainActivity before this earthquakes =getEarthquakeData();

like **ArrayList<> earthquakes= new ArraryList<>();**

you are seeing this error(java.lang.NullPointerException) because  **earthQuakeObjectList.size();** is null.

Comment: Thanks it solved the nullpointer exception, but still the data is not displayed on the app.

Comment: Now again debug your app and see the next error in variables of onResponse or onFailure

Comment: I'm getting data on the response now, also i'm able to add the objects in to the arraylist, but when i return the array list its returning null. So im not able to populate the recyclerview.

Comment: you need to notify your adapter about data changes call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after for loop in onResponse method

Comment: its my pleasure

Answer (score 0):

You got an empty array list from the response. Here are some changes in your api request

```
Call<JsonObject> call = earthquakeApi.getEarthquakeInfo();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) 
        {

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                JSONObject responseObject = response.body();

                try {
                        JsonArray jsonArray response.body().get("features").getAsJsonArray();

                        Log.e("Response.....", "-----//array//----" + jsonArray);
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++) {
                            Log.e("TAG", "---item---" + jsonArray.get(i));
                        }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JSONObject> call, Throwable t) {
            System.out.println(t.getMessage());

        }


    });
```

I just print the array objects list to show the data. You can pass this list to recycler view.

Hope, it works for you!!

Comment: Yeah , there was a problem in my json parsing, thank you!